# Trace application compiled by gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

I want to trace an application compiled by gcc. By tracing, I mean I want to the see address of every instruction executed. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: I have now made my own solution using ptrace. So simple.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is using GDB, of course.

Compile your code:

```
$ gcc -Wall m.c -o m
```

Trace it with gdb:

```
$ gdb m
> b main
> r
```

GDB will break on your entry function: `main`.

If this kind of trace is not good for you, try using [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) on linux, or [`dtrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) on Solaris, BSD or Mac OS X.

Comment: How can this be achieved by using GDB. What I would like is to see the trace at the end of execution. Steps?

Comment: But strace is for tracing system calls, right? Not for tracing each instruction.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: with dtrace you can even trace instruction. But I don't understand why **GDB** is not good enough for tracing instructions. Do you want to store the trace on file or something? Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, to save the trace in a file or print it on screen (in which case, I can redirect it to a file).

Comment: I think the best solution is using ptrace.

Answer (score 0):

Using gdb, you could turn on logging:

```
set logging file my_log_filename.log
set logging on
```

and write a recursive step macro:

```
define s
stepi
s
end
```

Using ptrace, just `ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP...)` until the tracee ends or gets a signal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this

> strace -i program_name

Note: this will print only system calls called from the desired program.